# Не считает частоту,выводит 0

Tags: c++

Частоту встречающихся символов рассчитываю по формуле

(количество встречающегося символа/длинна строки)*100

В итоге выводит почему-то 0.

Сама переменная frequency у меня в формате double,если бы было int конечно было бы понятно почему 0.

Но дело в том что даже при применение точки остановки и пошаговой отладки компилятор пишет 0.000000.

```
void calculate_symb(FILE *fd)
{   
    int max=0;
    fd=fopen("test.dat","rb");
    if (!fd) 
       printf("Ошибка!Файл не найден!\n");
    else
    {
    fseek(fd,0L,SEEK_END);
    long fsize=ftell(fd);   
    int n=fsize;
    cout<<"Количество символов в файле = "<<fsize<<endl;
    char* symv = new char[n];
    symv[n+1]='\0';
    fseek(fd,0L,SEEK_SET);
    cout<<"Вывод содержимого двоичного файла:"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fread(symv, sizeof(char), n, fd);
        cout << symv[i]; 
    }
    fclose(fd);
    cout<<endl;
    int l=strlen(symv);   
    cout<<"Повторяющиеся символы:"<<endl;
    for(int x = 0; x<l-1; x++)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            if(isalnum(symv[x]))            
                  for(int y = x-1; y>=0 && flag; y--)
                   if(symv[x] == symv[y])
                       flag = false;
            if(flag&&isalnum(symv[x]))
                   cout<<"\""<<symv[x]<<"\""<<" ->  "<<count(symv,symv+l,symv[x])<<endl;///Здесь выводится количество встречающихся символов
            double frequency = (count(symv,symv+l,symv[x])/l)*100;///---Здесь пытаюсь подсчитать частоту,формула.
            cout<<"Частота символа = "<<frequency<<endl;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
double frequency = (count(symv,symv+l,symv[x])/l)*100;
```

на

```
double frequency = (static_cast<double>(count(symv,symv+l,symv[x]))/l)*100;
```

PS: Выполнять подсчет символов в строке очень легко про помощи `std::map`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main(){
    std::string str = "What is your name?";

    std::map<char, int> m;
    for(std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it){
        m[*it]++;
    }

    for(std::map<char, int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << it->first << " - " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не в коня корм - с этой задачей уже обращение было, нет, все равно свои двойные циклы потянул...

Comment: Вы ещё пишите `std::map<char, int>::const_iterator` в циклах по коллекции? Тогда вам пора в `c++11`. Кстати, вместо `static_cast<double>` при наличии числовых литералов считаю элегантнее будет просто добавить десятичную точку.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что у вас

```
char* symv = new char[n];
symv[n+1]='\0';
```

выделено `n` символов с номерами от 0 до `n-1`, но вы обнуляете символ с номером `n+1`.

Затем вы `n` раз считываете по `n` символов...

```
 for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
 {
    fread(symv, sizeof(char), n, fd);
```

Но все это фигня, потому что переменной типа `double` вы присваиваете результат **целочисленного** деления, равный 0 (ведь `count()` явно меньше `l`)...

> Сама переменная frequency у меня в формате double,если бы было int конечно было бы понятно почему 0.

Ну вот вы и ответили. Вы же **вычисляете** `int`! что толку с того, что потом вы его присваиваете `double`?

P.S. Но ваш алгоритм... К чему все эти телодвижения с вложенными циклами?

Comment: назвать UB в результате записи за границы массива "фигней" - это сильно!

Comment: @gbg Да, потому что это не то, о чем, собственно, вопрос, и это как раз не влияет на получаемый результат (в данном конкретном случае, понятно). Забавно, что автор вопроса - это же надо! - ответил сам, но не понял этого...